# Can Azure Advisor look at more than 7 days CPU utilization data

Tags: azure

Can you configure Azure Advisor to look for more than 7 days CPU utilization, 7 days data seems very inadequate for a recommendation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/advisor/advisor-get-started#configure-low-usage-vm-recommendation) Azure document, I believe currently as per design the Advisor monitors usage for only 7 days. If interested, I would suggest to share a feedback under [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/919474-azure-advisor) UserVoice / feedback forum to provide an option for user to mention n number of days to monitor. Then responsible Azure product / feature team would triage the feedback, check feasibility and prioritize it based on the votes a feedback receives, etc.

Comment: Thanks, Krishna, I have posted the recommendation, to my surprise no one asked for it so far, am I missing anything, it seems very basic request, 7 days worth data is not good enough for any recommendation, no LOB will accept the recommendation this way.

Comment: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/919474-azure-advisor/suggestions/39400507-allow-customize-advisor-to-look-at-60-days-cpu-uti